# Stop bash functions clobbering global variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Here's an extract from a bash script to reconfigure grub

```
    OLD="/etc/default/grub"
    NEW="/tmp/default.grub"
    SEC="1"

    cp "$OLD" "$NEW" || { >&2 echo "Couldn't copy $OLD" && exit 1; }

    sed -i "s/GRUB_TIMEOUT=[0-9]\+/GRUB_TIMEOUT=3/$SEC" "$NEW"

    cp_if_change_confirmed "$NEW" "$OLD"

    diff "$OLD" "$NEW" >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    {
        CFG="$NEW.made"

        grub2-mkconfig --output="$CFG"

        echo "made $CFG from $NEW"

        cp_if_change_confirmed "$CFG" "/boot/grub2/grub.cfg"

        echo rm "$CFG"
        rm "$CFG"
    }

    echo rm "$NEW"
    rm "$NEW"
```

Those final `echo` and `rm` lines output

```
rm /tmp/default.grub.made
rm /tmp/default.grub.made
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/default.grub.made:‘ No such file or directory
```

Somehow `NEW` is being assigned the value of `CFG`.

Looking in `cp_if_change_confirmed`, which is a bash function, it contains

```
NEW="$1"
```

Which I guess explains the problem -- these variables don't have limited-enough scope.

But this is a maintenance problem -- I need to be able to include third party functions and know that they're not going to clobber values in the parent script.

Can I do this in bash, or is it a hopeless case and I just need to either be vigilant about variable names or use a real language?

Comment: In functions, use `local`. A real language would make sense for larger scripts, with Perl or Ruby you don't have to go that far from the shell syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `local`. Note that bash has *only* function scope (like `var` in JavaScript), not block scope.

```
myfunc() {
    local foo bar=$1 baz=$2
    foo=/tmp/$bar
    echo "value inside: $foo, $bar"
}
foo=123 bar=234
myfunc quux
echo "value outside: $foo, $bar"
```

If you have a block that doesn't need *any* persistence, you can call a subshell using  `( ... )`:

```
foo=123
( foo=345; echo "value inside: $foo" )
echo "value outside: $foo"
```

Note that subshells have the full overhead of fork() – they're independent processes. Also they don't let you choose which variables to localize – it's all or nothing.